# inflate custom Gallery Layout change properties fail

Tags: android, android-gallery

I tried to build my first custom gui element but I get problems when I try to change appearance or adapter (using Gallery) later in code.

My Problem: I can't change Custom Gallery properties

My actual Code:

First I create an XML which is the widget customGallery.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">       
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/toLeft"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dip" />
    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toLeft"
        android:spacing="40dip"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"/>

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/toRight"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dip" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gallery" />
</merge>
```

Later i create a test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lin_layout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <com.Test.GallerySlider
     android:id="@+id/choose"
     android:layout_span="2"
     android:layout_width="300dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    />

</LinearLayout>
```

My next Step was to include this custom Widget into my project and change the adapter from my Widget:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout lineLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_layout);
    ViewStub st3 = new ViewStub(TestwidgetActivity.this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramst3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lineLayout.addView(st3,paramst3);
    st3.setLayoutResource(R.layout.test);
    View st3InflaView =st3.inflate();
    GallerySlider gSlider= (GallerySlider) st3InflaView.findViewById(R.id.choose);
    gSlider.setNewAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.customGallery, new String[] {"1 ","2","3","4"}));
}
```

This is the Widgetclass I wrote:

```
    public class GallerySlider extends RelativeLayout implements OnClickListener {
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private Gallery gallery;
private ImageButton toLeftBtn = null;
private ImageButton toRightbtn = null;

public GallerySlider(Context context) {
     super(context, null);   
     init(context);
}

public GallerySlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
     init(context);
}

public GallerySlider(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
     super(context, attrs);
     init(context);
}

public void init(Context ctx){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.customGallery, this, true);

    toLeftBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toLeft);
    toLeftBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0){
                gallery.setSelection(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()-1);
            }
        }

    });

    toRightbtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toRight);
    toRightbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() < gallery.getAdapter().getCount()-1){
                gallery.setSelection(gallery.getSelectedItemPosition()+1);
            }
        }

    });
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, new String[] {"1","1",
                                                                                                    "1")});
    gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    gallery.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.h_sliderl);
    gallery.setAdapter(adapter);
}



@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    switch(which){
    case R.id.toLeft:   gallery.setSelection(gallery.getFocusedChild().getId()-1);
                        break;

    case R.id.toRight:  gallery.setSelection(gallery.getFocusedChild().getId()+1);
                        break;
    }

}


public void setNewAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> _adapter){

        gallery.setAdapter(_adapter);
        ((ArrayAdapter) gallery.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged ();
}
```

}

If I call setNewAdapter(ArrayAdapter _adapter) nothing change.. . I also tried to change the size of the gallery but it also fails(nothig happen). Is my approach false?
greetings marcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can detect is that you are creating your custom view two times.

The first creation occurs with the `ViewStub` when you set the layout.
And the second one, which doesn't get added to the `contentView` when you inflate `R.layout.test`.

You are setting the adapter to the second custom view which it isn't added to the view hierarchy.

Comment: Hallo, I change this. But the problem that calling setnewAdapter()  nothing change is actual there.. I thought notyfiyDataSetChange  will solve the problem. Any idea?

Comment: @marcel: Plz, modify the code in your question with the update.

Comment: Hello, I'am sry.. I found my mistake I now use View st3InflaView =st3.inflate();
        GallerySlider gSlider= (GallerySlider) st3InflaView.findViewById(R.id.choose); Thank You for pointing direction....